# NSTimer sometimes freezes when app is doing heavy computation

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, ios5, heavy-computation

I'd like to animate some loading points while the app is doing some computation in the background. I achieve this via an `NSTimer`:

```
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3f
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(updateLoadingPoints:) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
```

Unfortunately, sometimes, when the computation becomes pretty heavy, the method is not fired and the updating therefore doesn't happen. It seems like all the firing is in a queue which is fired after the heavy computation.

Is there a way to give the `NSTimer` a higher priority to ensure that it's regularly calling my method? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Are the timer and the other computation on the _same_ thread?

Comment: @JoshCaswell no, they are on different threads.

Answer (score 3):

NSTimer works by adding events to the queue on the main run loop; it's the same event queue used for touch events and I/O data received events and so on. The time interval you set isn't a precise schedule; basically on each pass through the run loop, the timers are checked to see if any are due to be fired.

Because of the way they are implemented, there is no way to increase the priority of a timer.

It sounds like your secondary thread is taking a lot of CPU time away from the main thread, and so the timers don't fire as often as you would like. In other words, the main thread is *starved* for CPU time.

Calling `performSelectorOnMainThread:` won't necessarily help, because these methods essentially add a single-fire timer to the main thread's event queue. So you'll just be setting up timers in a different way.

To fix your problem, I would suggest that you increase the *relative* priority of the main thread by *decreasing the priority of your computation thread*. (See `[NSThread setThreadPriority:]`.)

It may seem counter-intuitive to have your important worker thread running at a lower priority than the main thread, which is just drawing stuff to the screen, but in a human-friendly application, keeping the screen up to date and responding to user input usually is the most important thing that the app should be doing.

In practice, the main thread needs very little CPU, so it won't really be slowing your worker thread down; rather, you are just ensuring that for the small amount of time that the main thread needs to do something, it gets done quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The timer is added to the run loop it's been scheduled with. If you create the timer on a secondary thread (e.g. your worker thread), there's a good chance you also scheduled it on the secondary thread.

You want the UI updates on the main thread. Thus, you want the timer scheduled on the main thread. If your updates are still slow, perhaps your main thread can do less work, and ensure that you have very low number of threads, and that you are locking appropriately.

I suspect you created it on a secondary thread which did not run the run loop as often as the timer wanted to fire. If it is doing a lot of (prolonged) work in the background, and not running the run loop, then the timer would not have a chance to fire because the messages would not have the chance to be fired while its thread is still out processing.

Answer (score -1):

Make your timer call from a separate thread rather than from main thread. this will certainly keep it separate from your other main thread's processing which will give you desired results.

Comment: my processing happens in the background, not on the main thread. in my timer-method, I need to update the GUI, so `updateLoadingPoints:` needs to do stuff on the main thread. If I try to fire the timer on the background, my problem isn't solved unfortunately.

Comment: If you fire it in the background you can always use the CGD.   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    //update GUI
  });

Comment: you must be using perfromSelectorOnMainThread which will again require main thread to be free for your UI update. what you can do is you may pass the UI view to the method in your timer's method and directly update the UI from within the method. this will resolve the issue of waiting for main thread. good luck!!

Comment: @Eugene I'm doing it this way.

Answer (score -1):

Perform your computation on a separate thread, using performSelectorInBackground:withObject.  Always do as little as possible in your UI loop, as any work done here will prevent mouseClicks, cause SPoDs/beachballs, and delay timer handlers.

I suspect that it's not just your TIMER being unresponsive, but the whole UI in general.

Sorry for having called out the wrong API in my earlier revision - copy/paste failure on my part.

Comment: `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` will perform the selector on the main (i.e. the UI) thread. Since timers need run loops and most apps only bother configuring the run loop on the main thread, this will essentially accomplish nothing. You want `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`.

Comment: Jonathan - you're correct, I copied the wrong API.  I've updated my response.