# UITableView scrolling hacks after some time

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, nstimer

I have several `UITableView`, `UIScrollViews` in my app. The tableview and scrollview scrolls smoothly on initial loading. But after the continuous usage of the app for some 7-10 minutes the scrolling really hacks. I implemented lazy loading for `UITableView`. I have also a `NSTimer` running in the background for polling.

```
NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
pollTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self selector:@selector(threadStarter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[runloop addTimer:pollTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Is this the reason for the stuck in the scrolling of UITableViews.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: i thought mainly reason of looping of timer after ever 4 second your table Data will be reload that's why your scroll hacks.. may be.. please visit this quiestion :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787014/nstimer-sometimes-freezes-when-app-is-doing-heavy-computation

Comment: also visit this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862066/nstimer-is-pausing-a-while-when-uigesture-action-performed

Comment: Do you have any statistics of the `-threadStarter` performance ?

Comment: Polling is not for refreshing tableview. Its looking for any new updates from server @NitinGohel

Answer (score 1):

The one main reason for these kind of issues that cause the apps to respond slower over time is **"Memory Leaks"**.

Check if you are releasing the cells and its contents properly. Please refer [this post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial) to know how to debug memory leaks, if you are new to this.

Comment: I will check for memory leaks. But if its an issue with memory it will show memory warning while debugging or it will crash at some point, right. But here i never got a crash on my application due to memory leak